# Super pressure balloon but it vents over pressure

Tags: ideal-gas

There is one substance better than hydrogen for acquiring lift, namely not filling your balloon with anything. After all, the hydrogen is just there as filler, so the walls of your balloon don't cave in. (And if you use a rigid balloon, you'll need a metal shell to prevent the atmosphere from crushing your balloon, which is way too heavy).

$F_{lift} = (\rho_{air}-\rho_{gas})gV_{balloon}$

However, as your balloon rises, the outside pressure drops. Therefore, you could have a rigid balloon that vents gas to keep the interior pressure equal to the exterior pressure.

This increases your performance by $\frac{\rho_{gas}}{\rho_{air}} =\frac{M_{gas}}{M_{air}}=\frac{4}{28}=15\%$ (if we use helium gas and we assume the air is made out of pure nitrogen).

Why is this not done by, for example, project Loon (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loon_LLC)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am afraid you have not allowed for decreasing lift with decreasing air pressure. As you go higher the air becomes thinner. A rigid balloon venting helium gas would provide less and less lift the higher it went, because the same volume of air that it displaced would weigh less and less. A partially inflated balloon that can expand as it gains altitude and the air pressure drops would provide more consistent lift.

Comment: Of course, I forgot that allowing the balloon to inflate has its own performance improvement, as more air is displaced. Thanks!